kubespray cluster calico-kube-controller error
I built a cluster using kubespray and ansible.
ubuntu@control1-instance:~/kubespray$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                   STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
control1-instance      Ready    control-plane   89m   v1.28.10
customer1a-instance    Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10
customer2a-instance    Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10
developer1a-instance   Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10
developer2a-instance   Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10
developer3a-instance   Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10
developer4a-instance   Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10
developer5a-instance   Ready    <none>          88m   v1.28.10

By the way, when I type the kubectl get po -n kube-system command, the following results are obtained.
ubuntu@control1-instance:~/kubespray$ kubectl get pod -n kube-system
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
calico-kube-controllers-86554d78f5-hbpsn    0/1     Running   0                9s
calico-node-65s8c                           0/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-8lm8w                           1/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-8skv2                           0/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-bgkhw                           0/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-lg5vn                           1/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-ltb94                           1/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-tx47m                           0/1     Running   0                13m
calico-node-v78pn                           0/1     Running   0                13m
coredns-77f7cc69db-5p2sb                    0/1     Running   0                83m
coredns-77f7cc69db-w4njq                    1/1     Running   0                83m
dns-autoscaler-8576bb9f5b-rp9n8             1/1     Running   0                83m
kube-apiserver-control1-instance            1/1     Running   1                85m
kube-controller-manager-control1-instance   1/1     Running   2                85m
kube-proxy-5fgzl                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-664p8                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-79vfv                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-g2d5q                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-gkcdp                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-gpdb5                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-v2hp8                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-proxy-w2nbg                            1/1     Running   0                14m
kube-scheduler-control1-instance            1/1     Running   1                85m
metrics-server-5b7489969-f9p7d              0/1     Running   20 (5m20s ago)   83m
nginx-proxy-customer1a-instance             1/1     Running   0                84m
nginx-proxy-customer2a-instance             1/1     Running   0                85m
nginx-proxy-developer1a-instance            1/1     Running   0                85m
nginx-proxy-developer2a-instance            1/1     Running   0                85m
nginx-proxy-developer3a-instance            1/1     Running   0                85m
nginx-proxy-developer4a-instance            1/1     Running   0                85m
nginx-proxy-developer5a-instance            1/1     Running   0                85m
nodelocaldns-2bxjz                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-4w2q6                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-6r69f                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-8gj2h                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-djgws                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-mxq49                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-rhpkx                          1/1     Running   0                83m
nodelocaldns-vvhck                          1/1     Running   0                83m

I tried https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/4935 based on the link but the result didn't change.
Also, I put that phrase in the k8s-cluster.yml file.
kube_network_plugin: calico
calico_datastore_type: "kubernetes"
calico_kubeconfig: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"

The results have not been resolved.
I don't know why this happened.
